# Conditionally assign the value of a variable to an object's property that may be null

Tags: javascript

The JSON response I'm getting from an API has a specific property that occasionally has a `null` value. I'm using JSX and want to `.map` over the response, passing props to another component. I want the value passed down to be a non-null value I received from the API **or** a string of my choice. I've tried multiple things, all with the same result: `Cannot read property url of undefined`.

This is what I've tried:

```
{posts.map((post, index) => {
          let p = null
          if (typeof post.default_image.url == null) {
            p = "via.placeholder.com/350x150"
          }
          return <Post
                       key={index}
                       imageUrl={post.default_image.url ? "hi" : "bye"}
                       />
          })}
```

As well as

```
let url = typeof post.default_image.url == null ? default_image.url : "via.placeholder.com/350x150"
```

and then passing it down like like `imageUrl={url}`

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Don't you need `typeof post.default_image.url  == 'undefined'` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because default_image doesnt exist, and you cant get a property of nothing. May check for that

```
let p = post.default_value && post.default_value.url || "via.placeholder.com/350x150";
```

And yes that works ( called short circuiting ;))

Comment: Ahh, my very first attempts were with short circuiting but I was doing `let p = post.default_value.url || "via.placeholder.com/350x150";` without the initial check for default_value.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`typeof <anything here>` will *never* be equal to null. Even [`typeof null` is "object"](https://jsfiddle.net/vkt4mt8o/).

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
let url = (post && post.default_image && post.default_image.url) 
    ? post.default_image.url 
    : "via.placeholder.com/350x150"
```

Comment: What a convoluted solution ;)

Comment: @Jonasw its more code than yours but I honestly believe it makes the intent clearer for someone not used to the short circuiting in JS as used in your example. Its also closer to the OP's original solution.